# construct a deterministic PDA for the language

Tags: pushdown-automata

Can someone help me to construct a deterministic PDA for the following language:

$L =  \{0^n1^m | n \geq m$ and $m,n \geq 0 \}$

Here is my  suggestion : 
the states are z0,z1,z2 , z0 is final state , for the empty string , z1 should also be finate state :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are confused, here are four hints to get you going.  You will still have to think through the machine, but here are some of the big pieces:

1. Push a marker onto the stack that will tell you where the bottom of the stack is.  (Let's say, $\$$)
2. Every time you find an $0$, push a symbol (let's say, $p$) onto the stack.
3. When you finally find an $1$, stop pushing.  Start popping off $p$s.
4. If you reach the $\$$ before you've reached the end of your $1$s, then you've broken the $n \geq m$ condition.

Comment: what do you mean : every time you find an n ? everytime 0 has been read ?

Comment: I have a suggestion . Can you please see it and give me a feedback ?

Comment: I added my suggestion in my question

Comment: Make an $\epsilon$ transition (some professors will call it a $\lambda$ transition) for putting in your $\$$, because it is just a marker of the starting point of the stack - no need to eat any input yet. Also, you do not need to push or pop on every action. Use $\epsilon$ whenever you do not wish to push (or pop).

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand u . Whats is this ϵ transition and where to put it ? And is my DPDA right ?

Comment: $(q_0, \epsilon, t)$ means "From state $q_0$, don't even look at the input, but pop $t$ from the top of the stack."  $(q_0, 4, \epsilon)$ means "From state $q_0$, take $4$ from the input string, but pop nothing from the stack." Similarly, $\to (q_1, \epsilon)$ means "transition to $q_1$, but push nothing to the stack." You can even do things like $(q_3, \epsilon, \epsilon) \to (q_4, \$)$, which goes from $q_3$ to $q_4$, ignores the input, ignores what's on top of the stack, and pushes a $\$$.

Comment: Ok I understand now . But is  my DPDA right ?

Comment: I'm not sure, because your PDA is written differently than I have encountered. Did your professor say that there was an empty symbol possible for your stack?  I've not encountered that in PDAs.  That's why I recommended using the $\$$.  Also, what is $pp$ and $p\$$?